# Show more than 10,000 lines on single Line Graph in Web page

Tags: java, vaadin, highcharts

I am working on java web application using Vaadin framework. I am converting existing VB Project into java web application . In this project i need to show more than 10,000 lines on a line Graph . I tried Highcharts line graph it didn't work and HighStock which only shows single line in Time based manner. It was also not suitable to my project . Is there any possibility to show multiple lines (more than 10,000 lines each contains 2048 data points) ?
Please give any suggestion or solution for this.

Comment: 2kx10k = 20mb take care!

Comment: I just have to ask what the use case is for even thinking of doing this? Not saying you are wrong, just wondering what your chart is actually showing. Think about it... 10k lines of data with 2048 pieces of information...

Comment: That Graph is going to be a solid block of colour with that much data. Break it into multiple graphs if at all possible.

Comment: I am showing the Camera intensity summary in this Graph . X axis scales camera pixel value (2048) and Y axis scales RGB color values (0-255) . I want to know that it is possible or not to show the graph with more than 10000 lines . If not, should i break it into multiple graphs ? . It is achieved in VB Desktop application . But can not be done in Web Application .